# I have a new file type that I would like to handle in gnome how to get file properties?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus

I have a new file type that I would like to handle in gnome.

Establishing a new mime type, a new thumbnailer and a new application to display the file type is done.

But I need a new tab on the file properties page. This tab is analogous to the tabs for exif information for jpg files or for encoding information for video codecs, that says how long the video is.

The files concerned are embroidery files and the file properties needed to be displayed are things like phisical dimentions of the design, how much thread will be used and how many colours.

My belief is that with current gnome 3 this is not possible, am I right?

Or should I take a wider view that in Ubuntu, anything is possible, just may be a bit difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you will need to change the code for Nautilus to read that metadata from the file and display it in the file properties window.

[This page](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove) describes how to get started developing code for Gnome and [this page](https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development) talks about development for Nautilus.